# If $\gcd(f(x), g(x)) = 1$, then $\gcd(h(x)f(x), g(x)) = \gcd(h(x), g(x))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, divisibility

This is not homework, but I would **just like a hint**.  The question asks

> Let $f(x), g(x), h(x) \in F[x]$ (where $F$ is a field), and $\gcd(f(x), g(x)) = 1$.  Show that $\gcd(f(x)h(x), g(x)) = \gcd(h(x), g(x))$.

Say $d(x) = \gcd(f(x)h(x), g(x))$ and $t(x) = \gcd(h(x), g(x))$.  Then $t(x) \mid h(x)$ and $t(x) \mid g(x)$, so $t(x) \mid f(x)h(x)$ and $t(x) \mid g(x)$, which implies $t(x) \mid d(x)$.  If I can show that $d(x) \mid t(x)$ then I'd be done, but I am having trouble with this part.  Could someone give me **just a hint please**?

Comment: $F$ is a field, so $F[x]$ is a prin...

Comment: This should be true in any UFD. Since $F$ is a unique factorization domain so is $F[x]$.

Comment: Let's say I haven't covered PIDs or UFDs.  Is there an argument using first principles?

Comment: Have you covered Euclidean rings?     :-)

Comment: I know about EDs, UFDs, and PIDs (although I'm not 100% comfortable with them).  However, this problem is from Hungerford chapter 4, where he hasn't even mentioned ideals yet, so I'm trying to only use machinery he's introduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\gcd(f(x), g(x)) = 1$, there exists polynomials $u(x), v(x) \in F[x]$ such that
$$ 1 = f(x)u(x) + g(x)v(x), $$
which implies
$$ h(x) = f(x)h(x)u(x) + g(x)h(x)v(x). $$
Since $d(x) \mid h(x)f(x)$ and $d(x) \mid g(x)$, we have
$$ h(x) = d(x)m(x)u(x) + d(x)n(x)h(x)v(x) $$
for some $n(x), m(x) \in F[x]$.  Now $d(x) \mid h(x)$ and $d(x) \mid g(x)$, which implies $d(x) \mid t(x)$.  Coupled with the result $t(x) \mid d(x)$, as well as the fact that $d(x)$ and $t(x)$ are monic, this implies $d(x) = t(x)$.